# Проблемы с проектированием схемы базы данных

Tags: база-данных, uml

Проектировщики баз данных и разработчики - приветствую вас!

Я проектирую схемы базы данных для своего проекта. Проект подразумевает взаимоотношения между 'Производителями' и 'Потребителями', но если в качестве 'Производителя' может выступать как 'Пользователь', так и 'Организация', то в качестве 'Потребителя' пока что может выступать лишь только 'Пользователь' (хотя это только пока). Если рассматривать объектную модель моего проекта, то её основу составляют два базовых интерфейса - 'Производитель' и 'Потребитель'. Взаимоотношения будут возникать между экземплярами основных классов 'Организация' и 'Пользователь', причём класс 'Организация' реализует интерфейс 'Производитель', а класс 'Пользователь' реализует интерфейсы 'Производитель' и 'Потребитель'. Так, например, за некоторый период использования моего приложения некоторые пользователи должны и уметь продавать товар другим пользователям, и уметь покупать товар у кого-либо.

[image: Краткое UML описание проблемной области]

В перспективе планирую интегрировать в проект наиболее востребованные платёжные системы. Кто имеет опыт работы с платёжными системами, подскажите, какие изменения это внесёт в модель и схему данных. Необходимо ли мне добавлять сущности 'Юридическое лицо' и 'Физическое лицо'?

Я спроектировал ER-диаграмму согласно приведённому описанию, но она имеет ряд недостатков.

[image: ER-диаграмма, которая содержит ряд недостатков]

Во-первых, нет полного соответствия между ER-описанием и UML описанием. Нужно ли выделять отдельные таблицы под интерфейсы? Этого я не знаю. Ведь в таком случае по ER-описанию можно сказать, что 'Producer' и 'Consumer' - это суперклассы для 'Organization' и 'User', но на самом деле это всего лишь интерфейсы.

Во-вторых, мне нужна максимально простая проектировка, чтобы доступ к хранилищу был достаточно гибким, без лишних 'JOIN'-ов. Может, стоит вовсе отказаться от реализаций интерфейсов? Но я за использование всего богатства ООП. Можно ли на уровне базы данных использовать реализации интерфейсов? Мне известно, что использовать наследование можно. Но я не знаю, как эти трюки повлияют на производительность - поскольку все предыдущие проекты не требовали использования суперклассов и интерфейсов. В качестве реляционной СУБД я буду использовать PostgreSQL.

Если я буду вводить роли для таблиц 'Producer' и 'Consumer', то я должен буду наделить их атрибутами, свойственными сущностям 'User' и 'Organization'. С одной стороны, если количество ролей увеличится, то и количество атрибутов увеличится. Этот путь влечёт за собой перегрузку атрибутов таблиц. И для разных ролей некоторые атрибуты будут соответствовать NULL значениям. С другой стороны, один атрибут для одной роли может соответствовать нескольким атрибутам для другой роли. Например, атрибут 'name' для сущности 'Organization' соответствует атрибутам 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname' и 'username' для сущности 'User'. В-третьих, всё-таки хочется отделить друг от друга модели 'Producer', 'Organization', 'User' и 'Consumer'.

Пожалуйста, поделитесь своим опытом и реализациями успешных схем данных.